# Android Null Pointer Exception?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, nullpointerexception

I am new android developer, i have a class in which i am calling a webservices, i am getting json responce and want to save this rsponce in db and hashmap., but i am getting the following error..

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException
  at com.hb.hungryhub.DownloadReservations$LoadReservation.doInBackground(DownloadReservations.java:192)
  At com.hb.hungryhub.DownloadReservations$LoadReservation.doInBackground(DownloadReservations.java:1)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

my code is here.

```
 public class DownloadReservations {

public final static String KEY_RESERVATION_ACTIVE = "active";
public final static String KEY_RESERVATION_CREATED_AT = "created_at";
public final static String KEY_RESERVATION_DATE = "date";
public final static String KEY_RESERVATION_END_TIME = "end_time";
public final static String KEY_RESERVATION_ID = "id";
public final static String KEY_RESERVATION_NAME = "name";
public final static String KEY_RESERVATION_PARTY_SIZE = "party_size";
public final static String KEY_RESERVATION_PHONE = "phone";
public final static String KEY_RESERVATION_RESTAURANT_ID = "restaurant_id";
public final static String KEY_RESERVATION_SPECIAL_REQUEST = "special_request";
public final static String KEY_RESERVATION_START_TIME = "start_time";
public final static String KEY_RESERVATION_TABLE = "table";
public final static String KEY_RESERVATION_UPDATED = "updated_at";
public final static String KEY_RESERVATION_USER_ID = "user_id";
public final static String KEY_RESERVATION_RESTAURANT_NAME = "rest_name";
ConnectionDetector cd;
AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

DbHelper db;// = new DbHelper(getActivity());

JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();    
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> restaurantsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
boolean isParsingCompleted = false;
Context context;
JSONArray restaurants = null;
DownloadReservationListener downloadReservationListener;
boolean showProcessing = false;
private static String url_reservation = "http://hungryhub.com:80/api/reservations.json";

boolean isUserAuth = true;
//Users user;
Restaurants restaurant;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> bookingList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

String email,password, userId;
DownloadReservations(Context context, DownloadReservationListener downloadReservationListener,String email, String password, boolean showProcessing) {
    this.context = context;
    this.downloadReservationListener = downloadReservationListener;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.showProcessing = showProcessing;
}

public void startDownloading() {
    db = new DbHelper(context);
    beforeSync();
}

public void beforeSync(){
    cd = new ConnectionDetector(context);
    if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
        alert.showAlertDialog(context,"Internet Connection Error","Please connect to a working Internet connection",reservationListener,null, false);
        return;
    }
    LoadReservation lr = new LoadReservation();
    lr.execute();
}

class LoadReservation extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    int res_code = -1;
    String errorMsg = "Cannot get your reservations at this time, please try later.";
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        if (showProcessing) {
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            pDialog.setTitle("Processing");
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject objUser = new JSONObject();
        try {
            objUser.put("email", email);
            objUser.put("password", password);

            obj.put("user", objUser);
            res_code = jParser.postJSONWithUrl(obj,url_reservation);

            String response = JSONParser.getJson();
            if (response.contains("ERR:")) {
                int startIndex = response.indexOf("ERR:");
                if (startIndex > -1) {
                    isUserAuth = false;
                    errorMsg = response.substring(startIndex + "ERR:".length()).trim();
                    return null;
                }
            }
            String errorMsg = JSONParser.getJson();
            if (errorMsg.contains("Incorect login/pass")) {
                isUserAuth = false;
                isParsingCompleted = false;
                return null;
            }
            System.out.println(JSONParser.getJson());
            JSONArray jarr = new JSONArray(JSONParser.getJson());
            System.out.println(jarr.length());
            Reservations reservation = new Reservations();
        //  HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            for(int i = 0; i < jarr.length(); i++){

                JSONObject booking = jarr.getJSONObject(i);

                //map.put(KEY_RESERVATION_ACTIVE, booking.getString(KEY_RESERVATION_ACTIVE));
                reservation.set_active(booking.getString(KEY_RESERVATION_ACTIVE));

                //map.put(KEY_RESERVATION_CREATED_AT, booking.getString(KEY_RESERVATION_CREATED_AT));
                reservation.set_created_at(booking.getString(KEY_RESERVATION_CREATED_AT));

                //map.put(KEY_RESERVATION_DATE, booking.getString(KEY_RESERVATION_DATE));
                reservation.set_date(booking.getString(KEY_RESERVATION_DATE));

                //map.put(KEY_RESERVATION_END_TIME, booking.getString(KEY_RESERVATION_END_TIME));
                reservation.set_end_time(booking.getString(KEY_RESERVATION_END_TIME));

                //map.put(KEY_RESERVATION_ID, booking.getString(KEY_RESERVATION_ID));
                reservation.set_id(booking.getInt(KEY_RESERVATION_ID));

                //map.put(KEY_RESERVATION_NAME, booking.getString(KEY_RESERVATION_NAME));
                reservation.set_rest_name(booking.getString(KEY_RESERVATION_NAME));

                //map.put(KEY_RESERVATION_PARTY_SIZE, booking.getString(KEY_RESERVATION_PARTY_SIZE));
                reservation.set_party_size(booking.getString(KEY_RESERVATION_PARTY_SIZE));

                //map.put(KEY_RESERVATION_PHONE, booking.getString(KEY_RESERVATION_PHONE));
                reservation.set_phone(booking.getString(KEY_RESERVATION_PHONE));

                //map.put(KEY_RESERVATION_RESTAURANT_ID, booking.getString(KEY_RESERVATION_RESTAURANT_ID));
                reservation.set_restaurant_id(booking.getString(KEY_RESERVATION_RESTAURANT_ID));

                //map.put(KEY_RESERVATION_SPECIAL_REQUEST, booking.getString(KEY_RESERVATION_SPECIAL_REQUEST));
                reservation.set_special_request(booking.getString(KEY_RESERVATION_SPECIAL_REQUEST));

                //map.put(KEY_RESERVATION_START_TIME, booking.getString(KEY_RESERVATION_START_TIME));
                reservation.set_start_time(booking.getString(KEY_RESERVATION_START_TIME));

                //map.put(KEY_RESERVATION_TABLE, booking.getString(KEY_RESERVATION_TABLE));
                reservation.set_table(booking.getString(KEY_RESERVATION_TABLE));


                //map.put(KEY_RESERVATION_UPDATED, booking.getString(KEY_RESERVATION_UPDATED));
                reservation.set_updated_at(booking.getString(KEY_RESERVATION_UPDATED));

                //map.put(KEY_RESERVATION_USER_ID, booking.getString(KEY_RESERVATION_USER_ID));
                reservation.set_user_id(booking.getString(KEY_RESERVATION_USER_ID));
                userId = booking.getString(KEY_RESERVATION_USER_ID);


                //map.put(AllLabels.KEY_RESTAURANT_MISC, booking.getString(AllLabels.KEY_RESTAURANT_MISC));
                //reservation.set_table(booking.getString(AllLabels.KEY_RESTAURANT_MISC));

                //map.put(AllLabels.KEY_RESTAURANT_ARRIVED, booking.getString(AllLabels.KEY_RESTAURANT_ARRIVED));
                //reservation.set_table(booking.getString(AllLabels.KEY_RESTAURANT_ARRIVED));

                //map.put(AllLabels.KEY_RESTAURANT_ARRIVED, booking.getString(AllLabels.KEY_RESTAURANT_EMAIL));
                //reservation.set_table(booking.getString(AllLabels.KEY_RESTAURANT_EMAIL));

           //                   map.put(AllLabels.KEY_RESTAURANT_ARRIVED, booking.getString(AllLabels.KEY_SPECIAL_REQUEST));
        //                  reservation.set_table(booking.getString(AllLabels.KEY_SPECIAL_REQUEST));
   //                   

                restaurant = db.getRestaurantDetail(Integer.valueOf(booking.getString(KEY_RESERVATION_RESTAURANT_ID)));

          //map.put(KEY_RESERVATION_RESTAURANT_NAME, restaurant.get_name());
                System.out.println(restaurant.get_name());
                //reservation.set_rest_name(restaurant.get_name());
                //db.addReservation(reservation);


                //bookingList.add(map);
            }
            isParsingCompleted = true;
            System.out.println(isParsingCompleted);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            isUserAuth = false;
            isParsingCompleted = false;
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        super.onPostExecute(file_url);
        Log.d("flow", "MyReservation:onPostExecute");
        if (showProcessing) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
        if ((res_code != 200 && res_code != 201) /*|| bookingList.size() < 1*/ || !isParsingCompleted) {
            downloadReservationListener.errorDownloadingReservation(isUserAuth, errorMsg);
        }
        else {
            isParsingCompleted = true;
            ((Activity)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {   

                    downloadReservationListener.successfullyDownloadedReservation(userId);

                }
            });
        }
    }
}

DialogInterface.OnClickListener reservationListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
        // if this button is clicked, just close
        // the dialog box and do nothing
        dialog.cancel();
        removeFragment();
    }
};

private void removeFragment() {
    ((MainActivity)context).removeFragment();
}
```

}

Comment: read the caused by line you can find the null pointer there

Comment: What is there on line number 192.. ?

Comment: Which Line is `DownloadReservations.java:192`

Comment: how you creating  DownloadReservations?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? Especially line 192 where the NPE is?

Answer (score 0):

I think `restaurant` is null.. So it throws `nullpointer` when you want to get its name in `println()`.

So just check this two lines:

```
     restaurant =  db.getRestaurantDetail(Integer.valueOf(booking.getString(KEY_RESERVATION_RESTAURANT_ID)));
     System.out.println(restaurant.get_name());
```

And make sure that there is value in  `restaurant` ;